# Using NuGet PackageRestore with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have a simple class library project (with `Class1`) and have enabled NuGet Package Restore for the solution.

That imports the `restorepackages` task into the .csproj file.

I can compile the project with

```
C:>msbuild myproj.csproj /t:compile
```

And I can call the restorepackages task successfully before adding packages with

```
C:>msbuild myproj.csproj /t:restorepackages
```

However, adding any package will cause the restorepackages task to fail with an error 3.

It seems that the NuGet task is called with a wrong working directory, and you may actually fix the behavior by removing the workingdir attribut in the NuGet.targets file, that was added to the solution.

Edit the task like this:

```
   <Exec Command="$(RestoreCommand)"
           LogStandardErrorAsError="true"
           Condition="Exists('$(PackagesConfig)')"
           WorkingDirectory="$(NuGetToolsPath)" />
```

and remove the working dir:

> ```
> <Exec Command="$(RestoreCommand)"
>            LogStandardErrorAsError="true"
>            Condition="Exists('$(PackagesConfig)')"
>            />
> ```

It seems to work as expected both from commandline msbuild and within VS2010.

Does anyone know if this change might break any tooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be related to the issue "[Package Restore's $(SolutionDir) goes too far](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1900)"?

Did you check the injected `SolutionDir` property in your project file? It might be that the generated relative path won't point to the actual solution dir.